# Cannot do request with non HTTPS url

Tags: http, nsurlconnection, ios11, nserror

I'm just porting my app to IOS 11. Now my mroblem is that i always getting an NSError with NSURLConnection:
"The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."

Adding following to the plist.info does not help either:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 <dict>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     <true/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 </dict>
```

Does Apple requires https connections for Ios 11 now? I've only found articles saying it starts from January 2016, but my app still works without any problems. With Xcode9 , Ios11 beta i cannot get it work. Haven't found any informations about https and Ios11.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What did you find out?

Comment: Did not manage to get it work on IOS 11, so i switched to a secured connection. on ios10 it worked.